# Power Shell Remotely Activate Windows

Tags: powershell, windows-activation

So i have a pc with full access to the internal network (for what i need to do) And Im not sure if this is a code issue or my not understanding things.

But Im trying to activate windows 7 hp remotely on 300+ units. no domain, all remote pcs are workgroup. No license server,keys are in a text file, Firewalls are on both PCs. Same name for all, Different Ips, and the target PC has password protected account.

I tried to Activate it directly but kept getting blocked, i figured it was the fire wall but struggled to turn it off directly so now im tying to enable File and Pritner Sharing & WMI because that allowed me to activated it without issues. (No access to the internet)

```
ForEach ($IP in Get-Content "input.txt")
Invoke-Command { netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes }
psexec \\E:\FINAL\Enable FP\test.txt]][-u David [-p ] netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=yes
```

Comment: The title of the question has no relation, to the actual question. I came here looking to find out how activate windows remotely. This is a PowerShell remoting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domain or Workgroup , you cannot use this …

```
Invoke-Command
```

… unless PowerShell Remoting is enabled and you are using an user account that is in the local administrator group on the remote computer and the firewall must be set to allow it.

Setting up PSRemoting in a workgroup requires more steps to set it up.

[Remoting Week: Non-Domain Remoting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/29/remoting-week-non-domain-remoting/)

[PowerShell remoting between two workgroup machines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wmi/2009/07/24/powershell-remoting-between-two-workgroup-machines/)

There is no need to use psexec, if you are using PSRemoting. The is no reason to use PSRemoting, if you are using psexec.

The only reason to combine psexec and PSremoting, is that PSRemoting does not allow you to run as a local user account on the machine whereas, psexec will.

To install software / enable the features, the user account used must be a local admin on the remote host.

Your [Invoke-Command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) syntax is also not correct.
Your [ForLoop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-6) Syntax is not correct.

```
ForEach ($IP in (Get-Content 'input.txt'))
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $IP -Credential 'domain01\user01' -ScriptBlock {
        netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes 
    }
}
```

what version of PowerShell are you using? 
What are you not using the firewall cmdlet, vs netsh?

To do what you are after, use PSRemoting or psexec.